# Validate the custom list view controls

Tags: android-listview

I am very new in android development 
Here is my problem 
I created a custom list view consisting of text view and edit text

how can i validate that all edit text in custom list view are filled and  then only accept button gets enable?

Comment: Show us what you have and tried so far.. and the question doesn't make much sense..

Answer (score 0):

i have added text watcher for Edittext in getView() method
and in 
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {

```
        View v;
        EditText et;
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        Button acceptButton=  (Button) findViewById(R.id.Loginbutton);
        for(int i=0;i<listView.getChildCount();i++)
        {
            v = listView.getChildAt(i);             
            et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtedt);
            // and then i got the entered edittext values and make enable/disable the acceptButtton on the bases of Edittext values.

        }
```